# An alternative to the standard .NET XML serializer, suitable for cross platform communication

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have stumbled across http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html, but unfortunately the XML output it produces is formatted in a somewhat peculiar fashion, which makes it unsuitable for cross platform communication.

I have got fed up with the standard .NET XML serializer, so I am looking for an alternative.

Specifically, I would like it to be as potent as the Newtonsoft.Json serializer, but for XML, of course.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

There are two problems with the standard .NET XML serializer:

- Serializing a dictionary is a pain in the a*s
- Serializing a TimeSpan is a pain in the a*s

Yes, you can workaround by defining proxy members and all that. Why don't we have any problems with Newtonsoft.Json when doing json serialization?

Comment: It would help if you specified what you are missing in the standard serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out DataContract Serializer - it's used by WCF internally to serialize/deserialize SOAP-ed objects.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Returns object serialized as an XML string by using DataContractSerializer
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public override string ToString()
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, this);
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I will take it as an answer, because it does allow me to use both Dictionary and TimeSpan.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement IXmlSerializable on your class, this will require you to add 3 methods : 
1) ReadXml
2) WriteXml
3) GetSchema

Here you can specify exactly how your files serialize and deserialize.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{

    // Private state

    private string personName;


    // Constructors

    public Person (string name)
    {
        personName = name;
    }

    public Person ()
    {
        personName = null;
    }


    // Xml Serialization Infrastructure

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(personName);
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        personName = reader.ReadString();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return(null);
    }


    // Print

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return(personName);
    }

}
```

Heres a link to the docs. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want the Newtonsoft.Json model - serialization that just works.

Comment: Then you need the data contract serialzer